# ASP.NET Role Provider not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So I'm working on essentially a legacy app.  I have a login page which works, and redirects based on the user role upon login... so far so good.  But when the user hits the page to which they were redirected, the IsInRole method comes up with nothing, and redirects them to the login page.

On the login page I have:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(nameTest, passwordLogIn.Text))
{
    if (Roles.IsUserInRole(nameTest, "Admin"))
        Response.Redirect("/admin.aspx");
    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(nameTest, "Manager"))
        Response.Redirect("/admin.aspx");
    else if (Roles.IsUserInRole(nameTest, "User"))
        Response.Redirect("/mydonations.aspx");
}
```

Which works just fine...

And in the admin page I have:

```
if (!(User.IsInRole("Admin") || (User.IsInRole("Manager"))))
{
   Response.Redirect("/Default.aspx");
}
```

Which fails... I'd be very grateful if someone out there can spot what's happening.  I (needless to say) can't see the problem, and what's more exasperating these are snippets from other successfully operating projects.

Comment: Could you show **membership** and **roleManager** tags in web.config?

Comment: @Win this is what I've got:
 <roleManager enabled="true"><providers>
        <clear />
<add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
        <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

Comment: @Win and this:
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Looking at Intellitrace I see: A System.Security.Security Exception was thrown Requested Registry Access is not allowed" Needless to say, I'm now thoroughly confused, if it's throwing an exception it's doing so silently :S

Answer (score 0):

Since ***MemhershipProvider*** is ***SqlMembershipProvider***,  you want to use ***SqlRoleProvider*** for ***RoleProvider*** instead of ***WindowsTokenRoleProvider***.

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
      <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" 
        applicationName="/" 
        name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping... I think there may have been a typo?  I tried:
   <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
          applicationName="/"
          name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>

And have the same problem... any other ideas?

Thanks again!  I am sincerely very grateful!

Comment: Looking at Intellitrace I see: A System.Security.Security Exception was thrown Requested Registry Access is not allowed" Needless to say, I'm now thoroughly confused, if it's throwing an exception it's doing so silently or perhaps this is a red herring.